# Serving WordPress menu links in only HTTPS or HTTP depending on how it's accessed

Tags: wordpress, https

I have a WordPress site which uses [WordPress HTTPS](http://www.mvied.com/projects/wordpress-https/) to enable SSL when users access it via that protocol. However, currently the menu links point back to the HTTP version.

I want users to be linked to HTTPS pages while accessing the site over HTTPS, but not when accessing it over HTTP. Is this possible?

Note: I have tried changing the menu options to use `//` and `/` for the links, but in both cases they are just rendered as HTTP links.

Comment: See "How do I make my whole website secure?" [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/faq/).

Comment: Actually all the links are wrong in Wordpress. It's a big nightmare if you ask me... I tried to use it once, although it has nice capabilities (with lots of AJAX) the fact that links are completely broken made me leave that product.

Comment: Have you tried using the [official guide](http://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Yoast SEO plugin? I was just actually doing this on my client's site. If so, try going to SEO > SEO Settings > Permalinks > Canonical Settings > Leave Default. (I know canonicalization isn't what you're looking for, but the other two options are "force HTTP" or "force HTTPS.")

Earlier today, I was staying on the secure versions of the pages (when default was set) and staying on the non-secure versions of the page, depending on where I first started.

Also, depending on what kind of server they're on, you could probably do some URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you are enabling to force the user to use SSL links in settings, that will make all the pages use HTTPS, but not in HTTP. Make sure that your site should be in either HTTP or HTTPS, because only one is possible.

However, we can make some default pages like payment transaction pages or login/register pages HTTPS because they are really secure pages.

One more tip is, if you are enabling HTTPS on all your pages, your site will not be cached 
by Google robots, so use HTTP in that case.

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. Also, [the last paragraph is incorrect](http://hoisie.com/2011/01/19/yes-browsers-do-cache-ssl-resources-so-please-use-googles-cdn/).

Comment: @Gelatin The link in your comment is in regards to browser caching, whereas the OP was referring to caching by Google (without confirming or dis-confirming that).

Comment: Alternative evidence: GitHub uses HTTPS on all pages and it appears in Google's cache.